# Using SimpleForm inside DataGrid and ReferenceManyField | react-admin

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-admin

actually i try to use a SimpleForm inside a Datagrid and ReferenceManyField to show a joined table and also change this data. Showing the data and deleting works pretty fine but everytime i click on Save i get the following Error:

`

```
Uncaught TypeError: onSave.current is not a function
    at submit (FormWithRedirect.js:86)
    at Object.submit (final-form.es.js:1296)
    at handleSubmit (react-final-form.es.js:264)
    at FormWithRedirect.js:121
    at handleClick (SaveButton.js:57)
```

`

My actual Code:

```
<Edit {...props}>
        <SimpleShowLayout>
            <DateField source="date" />
            <ReferenceField label="Location" source="LocationID" reference="locations">
                <TextField source="name" />
            </ReferenceField>
            <ReferenceField label="Employee" source="EmployeeID" reference="employees">
                <TextField source="first_name" />
            </ReferenceField>
            <ReferenceManyField
                label="Customers"
                reference="bookings"
                target="data"
            >
                <Datagrid>
                    <SimpleForm>
                        <TextInput label="Vorname" source="customer.first_name" />
                        <TextInput label="Nachname" source="customer.last_name" />

                        <BooleanInput label="Anwesend" source="present" />
                    </SimpleForm>
                </Datagrid>
            </ReferenceManyField>
        </SimpleShowLayout>
    </Edit>
```

Comment: where is onsave function in your code?

Answer (score 2):

According to docs `SimpleForm` should be used with `Create` and `Edit` parent component as they pass `save` and `saving` to `SimpleForm`.

[source](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/CreateEdit.html#the-simpleform-component)

You can also try write your custom `onSave` function and manage `saving` state.

```
<SimpleForm save={onSave} saving={saving}>
```

Comment: Ah sorry i've not copied the whole code my false. I've updated it